# Crear Roles para Usuarios con Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

tengo una aplicación en Ruby on Rails, utilizo la **gema devise** para autenticar mis usuarios pero tengo que asignar roles a esos usuarios (Admnistrado Principal, Administrador de Articulos y Usuario). Quisiera tener rutas y vistas para cada usuario. Podrian decirme como podria hacerlo. Gracias

Comment: Podrías agregar una columna de rol al usuario y verificarla en cada controlador; o también hay gemas (como [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/README.md)) dedicadas a autorización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola anhade en tu migracion

```
t.integer     :rol
```

Dirigete al modelo de User y anhade lo siguiente

```
enum rol: [:"Admnistrado Principal", :"Administrador de Articulos", :"Usuario"]
```

Luego defines un metodo privado para setear un rol por defecto

```
private
  def user_default
    self.rol = :"Agente Comercial"
  end
end
```

No olvides llamarlo antes del registro para eso usas

```
before_create :user_default
```

Y creo que con eso seria todo en cuanto a los roles.